# How to modify Hololens Emulator's Human Input script, so that I can directly set the camera's rotation?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am trying to make a project where a Gyroscope controls the Hololens rotation in the Hololens Emulator. The problem is that I don't know how to modify the script that sends the default keyboard and mouse input to the Hololens VM.

Example situation: I open the Hyper-V manager, boot the Hololens Image, connect to it so that I can see the screen, and I have a window that connects to the Hyper-V VM, in which I have input boxes for each rotation (and position) axis, along with buttons for air-tap or bloom gesture, and clicking them or changing the values of the input boxes send as Human Input data to the VM, resulting in changing Hololens position/rotation or selecting an item.

After doing this, I can easily send information from a gyroscope to the Hololens Image, but the problem isn't this, the real problem is how do I send human input to the Hololens VM?

I tried to reverse-engineer the whole emulator, and I observed these things: The Hololens Hyper-V is independent of the actual Emulator, the XDE emulator only connects to the VM created by Hyper-V, and send the input as Human Input to the Hololens image.

Looking at the command line that executes the emulator (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.17134.0\XDE.exe" /name "HoloLens Emulator 10.0.17134.0.USERNAME" /displayName "HoloLens Emulator 10.0.17134.0" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\HoloLens\10.0.17134.0\flash.vhd" /video "1268x720" /memsize 2048 /language 409 /creatediffdisk "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.17134.0\dd.1268x720.2048.vhd" /fastShutdown /sku HDE`) I can see where the Virtual Hard Disk of the Hololens is (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\HoloLens\10.0.17134.0\flash.vhd`) and mounting it to the system, I can see a slightly modified version of the normal Windows 10, which is the Windows 10 Holographic. I don't see anything special, like the script which receives the input.

Looking at the Hololens Emulator XDE folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.17134.0`), I see something. It's a DLL file named `InputController.dll`, but I can't do anything to it since it's a DLL, not a script.

How can I achieve this? Should I modify the XDE emulator for Hololens? Is there a script in the Hololens Image (Windows 10 Holographic) that receives the input from the XDE that I haven't seen?

Thank you!

Comment: No one has an answer? I am trying now to reverse-engineer the XDE.exe, maybe there is something that sends the mouse and keyboard input.

Comment: Use PerceptionSimulator libraries to simulate gaze and other hand gestures. You do not have to tweak the InputController at all.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/perception-simulation

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I was looking for.